# MySQL left join optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have 2 tables:

- `formfill` has the columns `idmessage`, `value`, `namefield`.
- `fields` has the columns `namefield`, `typefield`, `optionsfield`.

I don't have any primary key. Relationship is between namefield columns.

My query  is:

```
select e.namefield,e.typefield,e.optionsfield,b.value,b.id
from fields as e
left join formfill as b on e.namefield = b.namefield and b.id=1011
```

This query is ok. But it runs very slowly (about 10 seconds). How can I make it faster?

Comment: you have added the necessary indexes to a table?

Comment: You need to add indexes. Can you please post the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT e.namefield...` ?

Comment: What is this query doing?  It is a bit unusual to see a left outer join with a restriction on the second table.  Often, when choosing an id, you want that id.  But this query is more general.  Do you really mean a right outer join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should post your query plan with

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

but low speed of query execution migh mean

- you don't have indexes, and engine has to do fullscan, so it's good idea to add indexes on fields you have operations like '='. The type of index may be 'hash' if you are using = or <>, and btree for operations like < or >
- the number of rows in right table is greater than one in left table by magnitude of 10 and more, so indexes wouldn't help much and you will need to think about partitioning the data